# OpenSSL 0.9.8zg used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1

Tags: php, openssl, macos

As part of the installation a PHP 5.4 cartridge from openshift.com on my Mac with OS X 10.10.5 in the Terminal I noticed a message about it loading OpenSSL 0.9.8 for compatibilty with PHP.

Later, trying to install getcomposer.org it is giving me a warning:

> Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
>   If you encounter issues, try to change the following:
>
> The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.  If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.

`openssl version` command in terminal reported `OpenSSL 0.9.8zg` 14 July 2015

Should I update to OpenSSL version 1.0.1?

Comment: From OpenSSL website: `The 0.9.8 and 1.0.0 versions are now out of support and should not be used.`

Comment: Also see [Warning: openssl-1.0.2g already installed when using HomeBrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36372000) and [How to upgrade OpenSSL version used by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37649413) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL 0.9.8zc or 0.9.8zg does not support TLSv1.1/1.2 which can cause vulnerabilities while downloading using HTTPS links.

You should update OpenSSL to latest version from official site.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a MAC OS X 10.10.5. You need to update OpenSSL doing:

1. Check the current version

   ```
   openSSl version
   ```
2. The ports tree has been updated

   ```
   sudo port selfupdate
   ```
3. Now, you can update your openSSL

   ```
   sudo port upgrade openssl
   ```
4. Check the new version

   ```
   openSSl version
   ```

If the error is still present:

5. You need to check the PHP version

   ```
   php --version
   ```
6. Change it to your newest PHP version

   ```
   vi ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   > ```
   >    export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin:$PATH
   > ```

   ```
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```
7. Check the new version

   ```
   php --version
   ```

Comment: Shouldn't you also explain how to install `port` ?